# Why does typeset has different results on bash and ksh when used inside/out of a function?

Tags: bash, ksh, typeset

Code:

```
#test.sh
test_func(){
var1="$1"
var2="$1"
echo "var1 before typeset: $var1"
echo "var2 before typeset: $var2"
typeset -l var1="$1"
typeset -l var2
echo "var1 after typeset: $var1"
echo "var2 after typeset: $var2"
}

test_func "$1"

var1="$1"
var2="$1"
echo "var1 before typeset: $var1"
echo "var2 before typeset: $var2"
typeset -l var1=$1
typeset -l var2
echo "var1 after typeset: $var1"
echo "var2 after typeset: $var2"
```

output using bash with input SAMPLE_INPUT:

```
var1 before typeset: SAMPLE_INPUT
var2 before typeset: SAMPLE_INPUT
var1 after typeset: sample_input
var2 after typeset: 
var1 before typeset: SAMPLE_INPUT
var2 before typeset: SAMPLE_INPUT
var1 after typeset: sample_input
var2 after typeset: SAMPLE_INPUT
```

output using ksh:

```
var1 before typeset: SAMPLE_INPUT
var2 before typeset: SAMPLE_INPUT
var1 after typeset: sample_input
var2 after typeset: sample_input
var1 before typeset: sample_input
var2 before typeset: sample_input
var1 after typeset: sample_input
var2 after typeset: sample_input
```

I dont understand why bash clobbers var2 in a function and why ksh changing the variable inside a function affects the value of it outside the function when re grabbing the value from $1. I assume this has something to do with their implementation of local vs global variables.

my desired output would be the same on bash and ksh and inside/outside of a function:

```
var before typeset: SAMPLE_INPUT
var after typeset: sample_input
```

used out of function:

```
var before typeset: SAMPLE_INPUT
var after typeset: sample_input
```

Comment: As you've found, `typeset` implies `local` when used in a function in bash, because it's an alias for `declare` there, so you need to use `-g` to make something global within a function context (as in, `typeset -g -l var1`).

Comment: Such are the risks of using extensions: They're not standardized, so there's never any guarantee that implementations will be identical in behavior. Put the `typeset` outside the function if you want the same behavior in both cases here.

Comment: I don't know what kind of meaningful, non-speculative answer anyone could give you as to "why". The behavior isn't standardized, so there is no standard to refer to. Maybe there's been discussion on the bash-bug mailing list, but asking someone else to do the work to look that up for you falls into the "off-site resource request" category of request (that's off-topic by nature here). "Because Chet didn't think preserving that level of compatibility was worth having two almost-duplicative codepaths for"? It's easy to speculate; it's hard (for folks not Chet) to provide a canonical answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I mean "why" on a technical sense, not from a design point of view.  I expect `typeset -l var2` to copy var2 to local so it is unavailable outside the function, but since the echo statement is inside the function it echo properly since it is local, but you can see that it is blank.

Comment: and using your answer we see that typseting is global for ksh so the value becomes lowercase, but after reading in again from $1 outside the function I would expect that value to be overwrite so the value becomes uppercase again since it is overwriten in the global scope

Comment: EDIT: actually thinking a bit more I realize my confusion: perhaps it makes a local var2 that is uninitialized instead of cloning the global value like what happens when accessing a variable in a subshell.  that makes the behavior in bash make sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, `typeset` is an alias for `declare`, which makes variables local when invoked inside a function unless the argument `-g` is added.

In ksh, `typeset` has different behavior depending on how you defined your function: With `test_func() { ... }` variables created with `typeset` are global; with `function test_func { ... }` they're local. Because you're using the `test_func() {` syntax, in your ksh code, `typeset` refers to the preexisting global variable instead of creating a local; so the original value is retained.

If you want identical behavior, you need to move `typeset` outside of the function, or add `-g` when the shell is bash; the latter can be done with a parameter expansion that emits `-g` only when `BASH_VERSION` is set, as below:

```
test_func(){
  var="$1"
  echo "var before typeset: $var"
  typeset ${BASH_VERSION+-g} -l var="$1"
  echo "var after typeset: $var"
}

var="SAMPLE_INPUT"
test_func "$var"
echo "var after function: $var"
```

...properly emits:

```
var after function: sample_input
```

...even on bash.

---

As for the empty value, you get that even on ksh if you change your function declaration syntax to make `typeset` create locals by default:

```
function test_func {
  typeset -l var
  var="$1"
}

test_func "SAMPLE_INPUT"
echo "Result is: <$var>"
```

...emits, `Result is: <>` when run in ksh.

Comment: line 3 has var1 instead of var but it is clear what you mean.  I upvoted but it doesnt count yet. I think if it explains why ksh does not overwrite the globally scoped value with "SAMPLE_INPUT" when rereading from $1 then it answers both halves of my question and I will accept as a solution.

Comment: A question shouldn't have "two halves" -- if you have two questions, they should be separately asked and separately answered.

Comment: @guest, ...that said, see edits, which show you how to get the behavior with the result being empty even on ksh.